# MySQL row number

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

Say I have a MySQL query, for example:

```
SELECT id, name, surname FROM employees ORDER BY id
```

The result woud be:

```
id    name    surname
 1     Peter   Smith
 2     John    Banjo
...
 1384  Will    Levenstein
```

While this is an ordered query, I can always assume (as long as I don't change the table) that `John Banjo` will come out second.

Now what if my query was

```
SELECT id, name, surname FROM employees WHERE name = 'John' AND surname = 'Banjo'
```

Could I somehow get what the row number would be in the first query?
I'm trying to do this in a much more complicated, but always ordered query, is there any way to archieve this?

Comment: Isn't the row number equal to id column's value?

Comment: @anpher: Suppose Peter Smith is removed, then the first id would be 2.

Comment: @Anpher I can't rely on that.

@Johan I need it to backtrace page on which will an item appear (page is limited i.e. to 30 items).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 SELECT x.id, x.name, x.surname, x.rownum
 FROM (
      SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 rownum, t.*
      FROM (SELECT @rownum:=0) r, employees t
      ORDER BY Id
 ) x
 WHERE x.name = 'John' 
 AND x.surname = 'Banjo'
```

Comment: This gives me an error (every derived table must have its own alias)

Comment: @cypher - added alias for inner query.