# select every other row in MySQL without depending on any ID?

Tags: mysql, sql

Considering following table that doesn't have any primary key, can I select every other row?

```
col1      col2
 2         a
 1         b
 3         c
 12        g
```

first select must find: **2, 3**

second select must find: **1, 12**

**is that possible?**

Comment: Consider this related answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997458/how-to-show-only-even-or-odd-rows-in-sql-server-2008

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In unique MySQL fashion:

```
select  *
from    (
        select  *
        ,       @rn := @rn + 1 as rn
        from    Table1
        join    (select @rn := 0) i
        ) s
where   rn mod 2 = 0 -- Use = 1 for the other set
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0bccf/20/0)

Answer (score 2):

Try this. I've adapted it from the answer linked below.
I tested it on SQLFiddle and it appears to work.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0bccf/28
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0bccf/29

Odd Rows:

```
SELECT x.*
FROM (
     SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 rownum, t.*
     FROM (SELECT @rownum:=0) r, table t
) x
WHERE MOD(x.rownum, 2) = 1
```

Even Rows:

```
SELECT x.*
FROM (
     SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 rownum, t.*
     FROM (SELECT @rownum:=0) r, table t
) x
WHERE MOD(x.rownum, 2) = 0
```

Adapted from:
[MySQL row number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576304/mysql-row-number)

Answer (score 2):

yes possible using temp variable

Example :

```
set @a := 0;
select * from car_m_city  WHERE mod((@a:=@a+1), 2) = 1
```

Explanation :

here in sql we declare @a( `set @a := 0;`) temp variable.`(@a:=@a+1)` now `@a` increment by 1.jsut like simple way to check odd or even

`mod((@a:=@a+1), 2) = 1` for odd data

`mod((@a:=@a+1), 2) = 0` for even data

Answer (score 2):

This works for me.

```
    SET @row_number = 0;

    select* from (
        SELECT 
        (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS num, col1,col2
    FROM
        TABLE1
        ) as t WHERE num%2=0
```

You can use mod 1 for odd or mod 0 for even rows

Answer (score 1):

This should work for MySQL:

```
SELECT col1, col2
FROM (
   SELECT col1, col2, @rowNumber:=@rowNumber+ 1 rn
   FROM YourTable
      JOIN (SELECT @rowNumber:= 0) r
) t 
WHERE rn % 2 = 1
```

This uses % which is the MOD operator.

And here is the sample fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cd31b/2