# Select only even/odd rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I'm trying to select all even or odd rows from a table in MySQL without using the ID field.
I tried this, but I suppose that it doesn't work since it's based on SQL Server:
[how to show only even or odd rows in sql server 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997458/how-to-show-only-even-or-odd-rows-in-sql-server-2008)

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: There is no such thing as an "even" or "odd" row in MySQL.  Tables represent unordered sets.  You need a column that specifies the ordering of the rows.

Comment: if you have id's in order you can retrieve where id % 2==0

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15578727/select-every-second-row-mysql-without-auto-increment-or-data-of-table]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming you have a column that specifies the ordering of the table, then you can use variables to do what you want:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, (@rn := @rn + 1) as seqnum
      from table t cross join
           (select @rn := 0) vars
      order by col
     ) t
where mod(seqnum, 2) = 0;
```

Comment: It works, thanks! Do I ask too much if I ask you to explain it? I don't understand the "@rn" and the "VARS" meaning.

Comment: `vars` is a table alias and `@rn` is a variable in MySQL.  You can read about variables here:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html.

Comment: I have a question: You are using PL/SQL?

Answer (score 5):

Try to use this:-

```
SELECT cols
FROM (
      SELECT cols, @rowNumber := @rowNumber+ 1 rn
      FROM YourTable
      JOIN (SELECT @rowNumber:= 0) r
     ) t 
WHERE rn % 2 = 1;
```