# MySQL query to print every odd rows

Tags: mysql

I have the following query. I just want my query to return every odd rows, i.e. row number 1,3,5... so on. At present it is returning all the rows of the above fulfilled condition.

```
select d.name as dept_name,count(*) as emp_number,sum(e.salary) as total_salary
from Employee e inner join Department d on  d.id=e.department 
group by department having count(*)<6 
order by sum(salary) desc, count(*) desc, department asc;
```

Comment: Which field contains the row numbers you want the odd values for? Remember, a database does not have to return rows in any particular order, and the order can/will change with database updates.

Answer (score 0):

Use mod function or % operator inside the query to identify even/odd rows.

Refer to this previously asked question:

[Select only even/odd rows in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25993936/select-only-even-odd-rows-in-mysql)