# How do I quickly select a sample set from a large result set?

Tags: mysql

I have a large result set **(R1)** (a few million rows) that I want to quickly select a sample set from.

I am using https://stackoverflow.com/a/25994039/601147 but it is far too slow.

Anybody know of a better solution?
Thanks

Comment: search the `limit` keyword

Comment: Show the table structure with `SHOW CREATE TABLE [table]`

Answer (score 0):

If you have an auto-increment column you can query for the smallest and largest ID and let your application generate `n` random IDs with `lowest < random-ID < largest` that you can select using `SELECT ... WHERE ... IN (<your-random-ids>)`.

The number of values in the `IN` part is limited on MySQL to [max_allowed_packet](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet). Hence, you maybe have to split the list on more than one `IN`-queries.

Also not all random IDs may exist, so you will have to check the number of rows returned and fill up the remaining list again with the same procedure until you have enough values.